# Windows Authentication problem while connecting to MSSQL server from JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, kerberos

Trying to connect to MS SQL server via Windows Authentification from Java application that runs on Linux machine. 
Connection string:

jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=MyData;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos

Got  connection error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:42aee675-fd0d-489e-af73-574ae5c304fa
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2670) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:131) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:399) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4306) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3409) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:85) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3373) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7344) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2261) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
```

How to understand this error and how to fix it?

UPD

If I remove `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` as following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=MyData;integratedSecurity=true;
```

I have error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
```

UPD 2

Leaving `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` and removing `integratedSecurity=true` as following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=MyData;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

gives error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'myuser'. ClientConnectionId:42aee675-fd0d-489e-af73-574ae5c304fa
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4548) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3409) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:85) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3373) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7344) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2261) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1921) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1762) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1077) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:623) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 0):

The app run on Linux machine, is that computer joined to a windows domain?

If not, then you may need to use a SQL authentication:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS;user=MyUserName;password=*****;
```

Otherwise, this one to try without `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` and default port specified:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=MyData;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Comment: No, my linux is not Joined into windows domain, but if I remove `JavaKerberos`, I have error `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for...` More details in question body UPD

Comment: Can you then try alternative: 
 jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.50\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=MyData;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos

Comment: Leaving `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` and removing `integratedSecurity=true` brings `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'myuser'`. More details in UPD2 .

Comment: "If you specify authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos but do not also specify integratedSecurity=true, the driver will ignore the authenticationScheme connection property and it will expect to find user name and password credentials in the connection string."  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15